# CoreData and the "Allows External Storage" option

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm doing a tutorial on CoreData and they talked about the "Allows External Storage" option. The documentation says "When enabled, Core Data heuristically decides on a per-value basis if it should save the data directly in the database or store a URI to a separate file which it manages for you. You cannot query based on the contents of a binary data property if you use this option." I understand the first part but I don't understand what they mean by "You cannot query based on the contents of a binary data property if you use this option". I feel this is important stuff, but I can't understand it. "You cannot query based on the contents of a binary data", what does that mean? I don't if it's my bad english or something but I can't figure it out.
The tutorial is "Core Data by Tutorials" from the Ray Wenderlich's tutorial book series. I highly recommend!

Comment: For future readers' reference, it may be helpful to post a link to the specific tutorial you were going through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

image the NSData you store is jpeg data with an exif header.

if you store the data inside the DB, you can use a predicate matching said exif data: e.g. something like (pseudo) "jpgedData CONTAINS author: dominik"

if you store it as a separate file, that query wouldn't work as the data isn't really inside the database

[note that this was explanatory pseudo code and I can't really think of a practical / useful example]

Comment: oohh ok I see so basically you can't do something that you shouldn't even do on regular basis. Cool! :)

Answer (score 1):

All that means is that if you enable that option for a property, you can't use that property in an `NSPredicate` when fetching objects. A fetch request is a query, and when you use a predicate you're fetching objects based on whether they match the predicate. That doesn't work if external storage is allowed for the property.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got it. Basically you can't use the image's raw meta data to look for a specific image, because you don't have access to the raw data. You only have access to the URI. Sounds logical and fair to me, since you could just extract the meta data, and store it in your CoreData model before saving the image as a transformable (if need be).